# Resize radius from 0 to 100 with CABasicAnimation

Tags: swift, swift4

I want to animate a circle. The circle radius should grow from 0 to 100. I tried it with the transform.scale animation. But of course it is not possible to scale a circle with a radius of 0. When I set the radius of the circle to 1 the circle is visible although it shouldn't be at the beginning of the animation.
minimal example:

```
let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()

let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: 0, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi*2), clockwise: true)

circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.brown.cgColor
let circleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

circleAnimation.fromValue = 0
circleAnimation.toValue = 100
circleAnimation.duration = 1.9
circleAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1.5
circleShape.add(circleAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

At the end of the animation the radius should stay at the new value.

EDIT:
Thanks to @Rob mayoff

Final code:

```
let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()

let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: 400, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi*2), clockwise: true)

circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.brown.cgColor
let circleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

circleAnimation.fromValue = 0.0000001
circleAnimation.toValue = 1
circleAnimation.duration = 1.9
circleAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1.5
circleShape.add(circleAnimation, forKey: nil)
circleAnimation.fillMode = .backwards
```

Comment: I'm definitely no expert - at CoreAnimation or math :-) - but can you "fake" it? The difference of 0-1 (or 0-100 versus 1-100) is small... maybe do 1-100 and at the beginning make it appear as such? A `UIBezierPath` needs a `UIView`, right? Start the animation by making the view visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you want to do is set the radius of `circlePath` to your final radius:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: 0, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi*2), clockwise: true)
circlePath.clone()
```

And then animate from a near-zero number to 1.0:

```
circleAnimation.fromValue = 0.0001
circleAnimation.toValue = 1.0
```

If you want to have the animation start in the future (by setting `beginTime`), then you also probably want to set the fill mode so that the `fromValue` is applied to the layer until the animation starts:

```
circleAnimation.fillMode = .backwards
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a radius greater 0. Then you can scale it down with  circleShape.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) 
before adding the layer. And then you could start the animation:

```
        let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
    let center =  CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / 2, y: view.frame.height / 2)
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100.0, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi*2), clockwise: true)
    circleShape.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
    circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.brown.cgColor
    let circleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

    circleAnimation.fromValue = 0
    circleAnimation.toValue = 1
    circleAnimation.duration = 5.9
    circleAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 1.5
    circleShape.add(circleAnimation, forKey: nil)

    view.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
```